# 403 Forbidden using symlinks on Fedora

Tags: apache, fedora, httpd.conf

I have tried every solution I found on google.

I tried putting followsymlinks on every directory on the httpd.conf file and changing allowoverride to all.

I don't forget restarting apache every changes I made.

I tried chmod-ding every directory. I tried turning off selinux.

any clue?

EDIT:

httpd.conf file: http://www.hastebin.com/alanavaxer.apache

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your httpd.conf file?  And do you have anything in .htaccess that could be overriding it?

Comment: Whatever I put inside the .htaccess on /var/www/html it would only cause Internal Server Error. I'll update the OP for the sample

Comment: Well that looks right to me... is it possible that your http conf file isn't being picked up and that you are actually configuring the wrong file? Apache 2.4 may be using the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file or you may be in a different /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ conf file...

Comment: I don't have an apache folder and based on what I found on google, it's /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: anyone please help? I can't really figure this out.

Comment: Does the apache user actually have read permissions for the thing you are pointing _to_?